# pip freeze и pip list ничего не выводят в virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

Возникла проблема в `virtualenv`. Команды `pip list` и `pip freeze` 
в виртуальной среде ничего не выводят, однако исправно работают вне `virtualenv`. Что делать?

```
 ~/PycharmProjects  cd test 
 ~/PycharmProjects/test  virtualenv venv        
  Using base prefix '/home/user/.anaconda3'
  New python executable in 
  /home/fiskirton/PycharmProjects/test/venv/bin/python
  Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  done.
  ~/PycharmProjects/test  source venv/bin/activate
  (venv)  ~/PycharmProjects/test  pip install flask
  ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are 
  not visible in this virtualenv.
  (venv)  ✘  ~/PycharmProjects/test 
```

Появляется такая ошибка. Создаю файл в ~/.config/pip/pip.conf
И в нем 
`[install]
 user=False`

Ошибка пропадает, устанавливаю в активированной виртуальной среде flask

```
pip install flask
Collecting flask
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/93/628509b8d5dc749656a9641f4caf13540e2cdec85276964ff8f43bbb1d3b/Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Jinja2>=2.10.1 (from flask)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/e0/eb35e762802015cab1ccee04e8a277b03f1d8e53da3ec3106882ec42558b/Jinja2-2.10.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24 (from flask)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/ae/44b03b253d6fade317f32c24d100b3b35c2239807046a4c953c7b89fa49e/itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.15 (from flask)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/42/3aeda98f96e85fd26180534d36570e4d18108d62ae36f87694b476b83d6f/Werkzeug-0.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click>=5.1 (from flask)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/37/45185cb5abbc30d7257104c434fe0b07e5a195a6847506c074527aa599ec/Click-7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/7b/ff284bd8c80654e471b769062a9b43cc5d03e7a615048d96f4619df8d420/MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, Werkzeug, click, flask
Successfully installed Jinja2-2.10.3 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-0.16.0 click-7.0 flask-1.1.1 itsdangerous-1.1.0
```

После этого пытаюсь вывести установленные пакеты

```
(venv)  ~/PycharmProjects/test  pip list
(venv)  ~/PycharmProjects/test  pip freeze
(venv)  ~/PycharmProjects/test  pip freeze > freeze.txt
(venv)  ~/PycharmProjects/test  cat freeze.txt 
(venv)  ~/PycharmProjects/test 
```

И ничего не происходит

Comment: Пересоздать virtualenv?

Comment: Пересоздавал несколько раз

Comment: А у вас что-нибудь установлено в этом virtualenv, чтобы эти команды могли что-нибудь отдать?

Comment: Да, flask, uwsgi

Comment: А можете дополнить свой вопрос логами, как вы создаете виртуальное окружение, как устанавливаете в него `flask` и так далее...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте загрузить эти данные в файл
Например в файл freeze.txt то есть pip freeze freeze.txt

Comment: Создается пустой файл

Comment: Сделайте эту процедуру через 2 е окно терминала

Comment: В файл записываются глобальные пакеты

Comment: Попробуйте сделать это через обычную командную строку а не через pycharm

Comment: Все, что в описании вопроса, делал в терминале

Answer (score 0):

А если явно?

```
python -m pip list
```

"Python" можно потом заменить полным путем к python.exe (venv\Scripts\python.exe)

```
 C:/home/fiskirton/PycharmProjects/test/venv/Scripts/python.exe -m pip list
```

Answer (score 0):

Для меня также такое поведение стало неприятной неожиданностью.
Решение:

```
pip freeze --all
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Упоминание на GitHub репозитории разработчиков](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4256)